# How to implement the Signup screen using MVVM + Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I'm an iOS developer, I am using XIB's (Not Storyboard) and I'm guilty of having Massive View Controllers in my projects so I've been searching for a better way to structure my projects and came across the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) architecture. I've been reading a lot of MVVM with iOS and I tried one small task which is sign up screen. But I am getting an error in viewcontroller class. If anyone helps me, It would be great.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I have added the screen shot please check it once

Comment: @Navya, can you explain the need of deleting the code while editing the question?, also there is not image right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error because you are calling the init method incorrectly, the code should look something like

```
let signupscreen = SignupViewModel.init(Firstname: "", 
                                        Lastname: "", 
                                        Mailid: "", 
                                        Mobilenumber: 0, 
                                        Password: "", 
                                        Confirmpassword: "")
```

and please use lowercase standard for parameter names,`firstname` instead of `Firstname` and so on.

Note that after looking at the viewDidLoad code more carefully, it looks to me like the whole init method is unnecessary since you don't need the `signupscreen` object for anything so an alternative answer is to just delete the code and initialize your ui components directly.

Comment: now also I am getting the error "Variable used within its own initial value"

Comment: @Navya  A my mistake, I didn't read the code correctly. you have to use other values when  calling the init method, empty values I assume.